# Auto round off no matter what

Tags: excel, rounding

I am trying to enter this number in an excel cell (in 2010 and 2016 office)
But the last number keep getting rounded to the nearest 10 y?
4966430838481101 this number is being rounded off to
4966430838481100

Comment: Excel has a 15 significant digit floating point precision. You cannot store a true number of 16 or greater digits. Store as text (preface with a `'`) or find another way of representing the number (search StackOverflow, Excel for 15 significant digit precision)

Comment: Thankyou. Now I know